# Message-based machine control pattern similar to ROS

Tags: c#, asynchronous, design-patterns, ros

If I have a single application running on a single computer but want to have multiple asynchronous threads running and communicating with each-other in order to control the complex behavior of machinery or robots what software design pattern would that be?

I'm specifically looking for something similar to Robot Operating System (ROS) but more in the context of a single library for c# where it handles the messages or the "message bus". There seems to be a lot of overlapping terminology for these things.

I'm essentially looking for a software implementation of a local, distributed node architecture that communicate with each-other much in the same way that nodes on the CAN bus of a car do to perform complex behavior in a distributed way.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your question has a lot of ambiguity. If you have a single application (read single process) then that is different from distributed node architecture.

1. For Single Application with multiple asynchronous threads

   ROS is not the best tool to accomplish this. ROS facilitates communication across nodes using either TCP or shared memory, neither of which are required for communication within the process.
2. For Distributed Nodes

   ROS can be a great tool for this but you need to understand its limitations. First, ROS does not guarantee any real time capabilities. The performance can of course be improved by using nodelets (shared memory) but again, no time guarantees. Second, ROS is not really distributed. It still needs a ROS Master which acts as the main registry.

I suggest you may want to look into ROS2 which uses DDS underneath. ROS2 has distributed architecture and you have the freedom to define your QoS parameters.